# iGraph R package bug?

Tags: r, igraph

When executing the simple code below to add weight to an edge from node 3 to node 5 in the network and looking edge weights it shows NA values there.

```
g<-make_empty_graph(directed = F)

g<-add.vertices(g,c(10))

g<-add_edges(g,c(3,5))
g<-set_edge_attr(graph = g,name="weight",index = c(3,5),value = 0.3)

E(g)$weight
plot(g)
```

After execution I get this

```
> E(g)$weight
[1] NA
> plot(g)
>
```

Is this a bug or I'm doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have specified badly the `index` argument when using `set_edge_attr`:

This will produce the correct result:

```
g<-make_empty_graph(directed = F)

g<-add.vertices(g,c(10))

g<-add_edges(g,c(3,5))
g<-set_edge_attr(graph = g,name="weight",index = E(g),value = 0.3)

E(g)$weight
plot(g)
```

As you can see from `?set_edge_attr`:

> index: An optional edge sequence to set the attributes of a subset of
>   edges

So now, let say you have another edge and want to set it a value of 10:

```
g<-make_empty_graph(directed = F)

g<-add.vertices(g,c(10))

g<-add_edges(g,c(3,5))
g<-add_edges(g,c(4,5))
g<-set_edge_attr(graph = g,name="weight",index = E(g)[1],value = 0.3)
g<-set_edge_attr(graph = g,name="weight",index = E(g)[2],value = 10)

E(g)$weight
plot(g)
```

You use `E(g)[1]` for the first and `E(g)[2]` because `E(g)` gives you back an array of all your edges in the order you specified them (1 will be c(3,5) and 2 will be c(4,5))

Best!